# How to put divs on opposite sides of parent div, with parent width relative to them on scaling?

Tags: html, css

I have a container div ***(that cannot be floated)*** with two children elements. I want child elements to be on opposite sides - first on left, second on right. On 100% browser width children summary width is less than container, but on greater scales it is not, so container should be greater too. How to set container to grow when it's gloat child grow?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.c]

**UPD:** something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/st4ooc0b/)
 I need all elements to stay one line in any scale.

```
 <div id="page">
     <div id="container">
         <div id="left">
           <div>first</div>
           <div>second</div>
           <div>third</div>
         </div>
         <div id="right">
            right
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <style>
    #page {
      background-color: grey;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
    }
    #container {
      /*this styles are needed to other parts*/
      position: relative; 
      clear: both;
      /*=====================================*/
      background-color:red;
      height: 50px;
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 5%;
    }
    #left {
        float: left;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    #left div {
      width: 50px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #right{
     float: right; 
     background-color: green;
     display: block;
     max-width: 200px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: what is green div width??

Comment: Post the HTML and CSS you tried please

Comment: @j08691 page code is too complicated.

Comment: @TEXHIK So simplify it and then post it. Just strip out all the stuff we don't need to see and provide us with the basic way in which you've created it so far.

Answer (score 4):

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

It should do that.
Google up FlexBox Introduction for good explaination.

Comment: Work with right div, but children of left div now going on the next line instead.

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

I've used `display:flex` to let the two divs line up nicely, floats only needed for the inner boxed

https://jsfiddle.net/070rk2e1/1/

Comment: With % of width no problems, but width can't be fixed. Left part contains more or less elements in differend conditions, and this elements has absolute withd in px.

Comment: I've updated my jsfiddle with more divs inside the left part to show you how it works.

Comment: Divs in left container going down, but I need them to increase parent. They must stay one line on all scales

Comment: You could give the left container a `min-width`. If you wanna avoid that I suggest using media queries to control the width of the boxes/containers on different screen sizes